# Does the resize() event only work for widths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, resize

I need an event that listens when the height of the window changes, and I've tried to use the resize() event, like this:

```
    var headerHeight = function() {
        $("#header-wrapper").css("min-height",$(window).height);
    }

    $(function(){
        $(window).resize(function() {
            headerHeight();
        });
    });
```

I thought that would work, but it only listens when the width of the window gets resized, not the height. Why is this? Am I supposed to use another event?

Thanks,

Comment: You can do this much more simply with pure CSS: `#header-wrapper { min-height: 100vh; }`

Comment: Yeah, but that works just the same way as the resize() event, it doesnt change when height is the only thing that resizes of the window.

Comment: [That is not correct.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/hjv8yksd/)

Comment: Have you tried dropping in a `console.log()` to verify the theory that "resize" doesn't fire for height changes?

Comment: @Pointy Yep, I've checked that and it doesn't fire.

Comment: [I get resize events on height changes in this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/t1Lqejpn/)

Comment: I think there may be other things about your page that are causing problems. I know for an absolute fact that (normal) browsers fire "resize" events when the height of a page changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is working, it's the code in the event handler that is the problem. You need to call the `height` method to get the value:

```
var headerHeight = function() {
    $("#header-wrapper").css("min-height",$(window).height());
}
```